# Amazon KMS - Intended purpose

Tags: node.js, amazon-kms

I am considering to use KMS for my specific scenario in NodeJS application. After reading a lot on either Amazon KMS and other blogs, I have fair understanding what it does.
Before I start implementation, I would need to get some an idea if I am on the correct path.
In my scenario, I have a configuration file, that contains sensitive data. That file is used to bootstrap my application, such as DB connections, and other secrets.
On load time, that file is parsed (residing in project root), parsed as object and later used by my application.

My idea, is to encrypt that file and have it reside in project root. And on application startup, call KMS service to decrypt it and use it as I use it before.

Is this the correct understanding that I have?